# jquery html manipulation does not work on the select inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/7FfMd/6/

run the code, then select "E" from the drop down, another input box appear, however I cannot select option B from the second input.

How can I fix it.

For some reason, I when I select option "D" from the first input again, the second select box does not update too.

Thanks

Comment: You are binding the `change` event handler to an ancestor of both select elements. That means when you change the second one, the handler is triggered and it is replaced by HTML again, which selects the first element again.

Comment: @shiro if any of the below answers were useful to you, then you should accept one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you catch the change event on the div that surrounds both dropdowns. When you change the second dropdown, the event handler will be triggered and remove the dropdown where you made the selection and replace it with a new dropdown.

If you want to bind the change event to the parent element, you need to check in which dropdown the change was made (using `event.target`), so that you don't recreate all the dropdowns. If you use `delegate` to bind the event handler, `this` will contain the element where the change was made:

```
jQuery('.change').delegate('select', 'change', function() { ... });
```

It might be simpler to bind the event for each select, then you don't have to check wich dropdown that caused the event. If you use `delegate`, you can bind the event eventhough the element doesn't exist yet, but you need to put a class, name or id on the dropdowns so that they can be identified:

```
jQuery('.change').delegate('#firstDropdown', 'change', function() { ... });
jQuery('.change').delegate('#secondDropdown', 'change', function() { ... });
```

Comment: I have a lot of select boxes, and also input field inside the "change" class (the div tag). That is why I want the event fire on the "change" class whenever there is a change in the input field. I have modified some code here http://jsfiddle.net/7FfMd/16/ . There is still error, which I cannot select E then select B. How can I fixed it? Thank you

Comment: @shiro: You can use the `target` property of the event object to find out which element caused the event: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/7FfMd/18/

Answer (score 1):

You were not getting the `val` of the input, but were getting the `val` of the div containing the input:

```
var testVar= jQuery('#placeholder2').val();
```

Should be

```
var testVar = jQuery('#placeholder2 select').val();
```

Also, the `change` subscriber should only be on the select, not the div also (to avoid the event firing when the second `select` is changed):

```
jQuery('.change').change(function() {
```

Should be

```
jQuery('.change select').change(function() {
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/7FfMd/9/) for updated version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. I need the event firing on the second select is changed as well. So, I would keep jQuery('.change').change(function() {

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've bound the `change` event handler to the `<div>` element that contains both `<select>` elements. Whenever you change any of those `<select>` elements, the change event bubbles up to the `<div>`. That works fine for the first one, but when you change the second it's firing that code again and replacing the entire `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're accessing the selected value with

```
var testVar= jQuery('#placeholder2').val();
```

This tries to get `.val()` from the div, not the select. Try this:

```
var testVar= jQuery('#placeholder2 select').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that when you add new elements, your previously applied methods won't have been applied to them.

You will need to apply the event code to the new elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a div that have the class .change. So the function are handled by all change by its children.

Have a look at this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7FfMd/13/

Answer (score 0):

your jquery was wrong.
here is my answer
Markup is as below

```
<div class='change'>
    <div id="placeholder2" style="width:600px;">
        <select>
            <option selected="selected">D</option>
        <option >E</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery should be like this.

```
jQuery('#placeholder2>select').change(function(){   
    var testVar= $(this).val();
    alert(testVar);
    if (testVar == "D")
    {
        var htmlString = '<select><option>C</option></select>';
        jQuery('#placeholder').html(htmlString);
    } else
    {
        var htmlString = '<select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select>';
        jQuery('#placeholder').html(htmlString);
    }
});
```